# Meteor : how to publish custom JSON data?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

**Edit: The solution I used is @Kyll's one.**

**Suppose the server side objects I'd like to return are "complicated" to build and need different attributes from different collections.**

I first tried:
/server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('myCustomDocument', function(){
    // suppose here that I need to X.find() different collections
    // and create a complex Array of JSON data (which contains different
    // attributes from different Collections
    return [
            {appName: 'aName',
             category: 'catName',
             anotherField: 'something'},
            (...)
        ];
});
```

It doesn't work because it's not returning a cursor. What I want to do is to create a document (or an array of documents) which is built from different collections.
I do not need to observe the changes on that document.

I have created a collection for it :

/collections/myCollection.js

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection');
```

On the client side, using ***iron-router***, what I tried to do is:

/lib/router.js

```
this.route('myPage',{
    path: '/myPage',
    waitOn: function(){ return Meteor.subscribe('myCollection'); },
    data: function(){ return MyCollection.find(); }
});
```

How would I achieve the sending of non-reactive data to the client?

Comment: Did you try with a Meteor `method`? If so, why are you trying to use a Collection instead?

Comment: I did not try, I will right now. It seems quite obvious actually... i'm quite new :D Thanks, I tell you in a few minute. :-)

Comment: Do you want other web apps to be able to get the json data or are you consuming the json data in app?

Comment: @Nate I am consuming the data in the same app.

Comment: @Kyll , with a Meteor.Method, I'll have to set data in the Session to use it in my Template? It seems weird, no?

Comment: FYI Meteor.Collection is deprecated, Mongo.Collection is correct now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meteor [Pubs/Subs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) are made for data reactivity. If you don't need reactivity but some one-shot data the server computes for you and sends back, you need a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)!

```
// Server code
Meteor.methods('getComplexData', function() {
  var complexData = { /* make your complex data */ };
  return complexData;
});
```

```
// Client code
Meteor.call('getComplexData', function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    // Handle error
  }
  else {
    Session.set('complexData', data);
  }
});
```

[More about Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session)

Comment: Hi @Kyll, thank you for your answer. The complex data I'm building is needed only in one page of the application. So isn't it "bad" to set it in the Session?

Comment: You would need a different structure yep... If you really are concerned, you could use a [Reactive-var](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) and control its deletion, maybe within a [Template.destroyed](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_destroyed) callback.

Answer (score 6):

Using a method probably makes more sense if the data is not going to be changed very often. The publish/subscribe pattern is also possible here but instead of returning a cursor or anything, you will need to use the publication "gears" manually, like this:

```
Meteor.publish("myCustomPublication", function () {
  // here comes some custom logic
  this.added("myCollection", someUniqueId, someCustomData);
  this.ready(); // without this waitOn will not work
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think I will use Meteor method and Session :)