# MeteorJS : Template rendered & Meteor method call

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor, iron-router

This question follows my previous one : [Meteor: How to publish custom JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812306/meteor-how-to-publish-custom-json-data)

I created a Meteor method building a complex JSON (built with different collections etc.). With those datas I need to build a chart using D3.js.

I used to set the data in the Session but as I realized they need to be refreshed each time I am reaching the page, it does not work properly.

Obviously there is something I did not understand in the mechanics, but here is my code :

```
Template.myPage.rendered = function(){

    var data = Meteor.call('myData');

    var svgContainer = d3.select("#svg");

    var margin = 40;
    var width = parseInt(d3.select("#svg").style('width'),10);
    var height = parseInt(d3.select("#svg").style('height'),10);
    // ... some more D3 code where I need the data
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
"Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: data is undefined
```

**I have already tried to call the Meteor Method outside the Template and put the result in the Session (in the callback function), but it did not work. I've also tried to use reactive var, but I couldn't make it.**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to twitter and @callmephilip** I found the answer (and I am ashamed I couldn't find it myself ! :D)

The only thing to do is to **put all the d3 code inside the method callback** :

```
Template.myPage.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.call('myData', function(err, result){
        if(err){
           console.log(err);
        }else{
             // all the D3.js code 
        }
    });
};
```

Have a good day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get the `"undefined"` error when you are trying to use a variable without a value.

```
console.log(data) //return undefined
```

Based on what you say, the Meteor.method returns a `JSON` who depends on other collections.

So I think the best option you have here is to use a `waitOn` on the `myPage` Template.

```
waitOn:function(){
 //return all the collection that the JSON depends
}
```

You can try with the session, and using a Tracker too.

```
var data = Meteor.call('myData');
Session.set('data',data)

//and later

     Template.myPage.rendered = functiopn(){
       Tracker.autorun(function(){
         var data = Session.get('data')
          if(data === undefined){
           //this is the long way
           console.log("Wait the data value still undefined")
          }else{
           //load all the D3 stuff
           console.log(data)
          }
       });
     }
```

GL

Comment: Hi, thank you. I can't waitOn all the collections because there are too many entries I need - way too many to be sent on the client side.

Comment: Well use the `Session` and the `tracker`, to fire the `D3` code when data its `!== undefined`

Comment: Also, the problem with the `Meteor.call('myData')` and set it in the Session is that it does not update when I leave the page and go back on it :(

Comment: hmm what happened if you use the `Meteor.call('myData')` and a simple if `statemt` inside a `TrackerAutorun` checking when data its `!== undefined`

Comment: It doesn't update. If I have 8 items on my D3 chart, and leave the page, do stuff so I should have 9 items on the chart. When I go again on the chart page I still have 8 items... unless I restart the application :(

Comment: I was facing the same issue months ago, but on a `jQuery carrousel`, and i remember the solution was putting all the code inside an `anonymous function`(like a package) and initialize the function inside a `Collection.subscribe`, but since you say that the `JSON` depends on many collections, the only solution you have here its `Tracker.afterun or flush` i guess

Comment: Would you explain a little bit more about Tracker.flush or afterun? I read the documentation, but it's not all clear to me :-)

Comment: In my mind it's crazy to face an issue for my example. What I want to do is just ask something like "each time I go on this page, ask the server to give you some data, and deal with it"... doesn't seem crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I would try smth like this:

```
Template.myPage.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.call('myData', function(error,data){
       // if !error, data should be good
       var svgContainer = d3.select("#svg");

       var margin = 40;
       var width = parseInt(d3.select("#svg").style('width'),10);
       var height = parseInt(d3.select("#svg").style('height'),10);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "meteor-reactive-method". Here's an inline link to https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method

then in client

```
 Template.myPage.rendered = functiopn(){
   Tracker.autorun(function(){
     var data = ReactiveMethod.call('myData');
      if(data === undefined){
       //this is the long way
       console.log("Wait the data value still undefined")
      }else{
       //load all the D3 stuff
       console.log(data)
      }
   });
 }
```

in server

```
 Meteor.methods({
  myData: function() {
    return CollectionName.find().fetch()
 }
})
```